# Transit visa for Dubai for Iraqi citizen

Tags: transit-visas, dubai, dxb, iraqi-citizens, doh

I want to get a round ticket to Dubai then to Srilanka.

I travel to Dubai by Qatar Airways which stops in Doha then goes to Dubai, then travel to Srilanka and return to Dubai by another airline.

Do I need a transit visa for Dubai both times?

Comment: What is your nationality? Whether you need a visa is often based on your nationality.

Comment: I have iraqi passport, and yes we need visa to everywhere

Comment: Unrelated, but I hope you enjoy your time in Sri Lanka. If you have any questions about that part of your trip, don't hesitate to contact me.

Comment: Thank you Joel Damien till now I don't have because I'm worried about transit airports and its difficulties because our passport is one of worst in the world

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Timatic (the visa system most airlines use), Iraqi citizens do not require a visa when transiting UAE airports as long as they are departing from the same airport within 24 hours of arrival.  You will NOT be allowed to go landside, however especially at Dubai there is no need to.

Note that as for many countries, UAE does not allow entry or transit to holders of Iraqi "S" series passports (ie, non-machine readable passports)

Comment: The S-series passport is also handwritten. These are readily identifiable as they do not look anything like current passports of most countries. Some countries (such as the US) will not even honor visas in S-series passports presented with a current passport. Iraqis not holding an A-series biometric passport or G-series machine readable passport are well advised to obtain a current A-series biometric passport.

Comment: I have the A-series passport I think the S-series in no more used all replaced by G and A series

Comment: My trip will be...  ISU-DOH-DXB and the return DXB-DOH-ISU both BY QATAR AIRWAYS between them DXB-CMB and CMB-DXB either by FlyDubai or Omanair knowing that qatar and oman use terminal 1  but flydubai use terminal 2